# Rscript not producing jpg output in cluster computing

Tags: r, cluster-computing, sh, rscript

I have an Rscript called `iHS.two.hist.R`. I have a .sh script called `iHS.2.hist.sh` When I run my Rscript in my directory, I get my jpeg output. When I call my Rscript in the .sh script, I do not get my jpeg output. I check the error logs and it's empty. I check the .log and it's empty. I should be getting a `null device 1` in the .log.

My Rscript is

```
###############cut columns we don't need
###
#cut -f1,2,3,4 /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/matched_snps_annotated.txt > /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/cut.matched_snps_annotated.txt
#cut -f1,2 /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/input_snps_insufficient_matches.txt > /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/cut.input_snps_insufficient_matches.txt
###
###############only needed columns remain

#read in data
#module load R
#R
###############read in data
load("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/iHS_Fst.rda")
###
data <- read.table("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/SNPsnap_top1_adhd_3_5k/matched_snps.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
insufficient <- read.table("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/SNPsnap_top1_adhd_3_5k/cut.input_snps_insufficient_matches.txt", header=TRUE)
###
data2 <- data[!(data$Input_SNP %in% insufficient$snpID),]
###############data2 is 100% matched



############### get rsID as first column
###
map <- read.table("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/SNPsnap_top1_adhd_3_5k/input_snps_identifer_mapping.txt", header=TRUE)
###
colnames(map)[1] <- "Input_SNP"
data3 <- merge(map, data2, by="Input_SNP", all=FALSE)
data3$Input_SNP <- NULL
colnames(data3)[1] <- "Input_SNP"
###############data3 is 100% match with rsID first column

###############read in annotated and match everything to rsID
###
annotated <- read.table("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/SNPsnap_top1_adhd_3_5k/cut.matched_snps_annotated.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
###
library(reshape2)
m1<-melt(data3,id.vars="Input_SNP")
m2<-transform(annotated,variable=paste0("Set_",set),value=snpID)
m<-merge(m1,m2)
out<-dcast(m,Input_SNP~variable,function(x) x[1],value.var="rsID")
###############out is table of rsIDs

###############replace rsid with iHS
data4 <- apply(out, 2, function(x) iHS_CEU.whole_genome.pvalues$iHS[match(x, iHS_CEU.whole_genome.pvalues$snpID)])
data5 <- data4[rowSums(is.na(data4)) < 0.25*ncol(data4), ]
###
write.table(data5, file="/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/iHS.match.top1_adhd_3_5k", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep="\t",)
###


###############percentage
dec <- colSums(data5 > 2.0, na.rm=TRUE)/colSums(!is.na(data5))
percent <- dec*100


###############find z-score and p
pop_sd <- sd(dec[-1])
pop_mean <- mean(dec[-1])
z <- (dec[1] - pop_mean)/pop_sd
p <- pnorm(-abs(z))

###############make histogram of iHS
###
jpeg("/group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/iHS.two.top1_adhd_3_5k.hist.jpg")
hist(percent[-1], breaks=seq(0,30,by=0.25), main="% Matched SNPs w/ iHS > 2.0 for ADHD", xlab="%")
###
abline(v=percent[1], col="red", lwd=2)
text(x=25, y=11, labels=bquote(P == .(p)))
dev.off()
#done with iHS plot
```

My .sh script is:

```
#PBS -N iHS_2_plot
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l mem=4gb
#PBS -o $HOME/${PBS_JOBNAME}.o${PBS_JOBID}.log
#PBS -e $HOME/${PBS_JOBNAME}.e${PBS_JOBID}.err

###############related commands
###edit it
#code in qsub


###############cut columns we don't need
###
cut -f1,2,3,4 /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/matched_snps_annotated.txt > /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/cut.matched_snps_annotated.txt
cut -f1,2 /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/input_snps_insufficient_matches.txt > /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/test/SNPsnap_mdd_5_100/cut.input_snps_insufficient_matches.txt
###
###############only needed columns remain


module load R
###
Rscript /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/iHS.two.hist.R

###
```

I'm completely befuddled. I have no idea how to trouble shoot this, or if this is just a simple mistake or if I have to restructure everything. I have tried running this code before on a smaller data file and it worked. Took about 30 minutes for a 100 column, 1600 row data set. Now I'm working on a 30 row, 5,000 column data set. The job took about 3:00:00 before it "completed' and then the error and .log files were empty. Any help?!?

Comment: Typically when I run into these issues its about file permissions, but you said it runs for a smaller data but not for a larger one. Are you able to run the larger data in your directory?

Comment: File permissions? How can I fix this? change them all to group? If you look in my Rcode, it doesn't even give me the `write.table` output. So something is going wrong before then. I am having running it in my directory because it's a `ssh` directory and my pipeline keeps breaking. How can that be fixed?

Comment: @Rohit, I was having the same issue with the smaller data before. But I deleted some of the `###comments` and got rid of a `cd /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter` before my `module load R` in my `.sh` script